# Comparing 2 lists (nested with normal)

Tags: python-2.7

Compare two lists:

```
abc=[[a,b],[c],[x,y,z]]
pqr=[a,b,x,y,z]
```

Print the matched strings.

I want the output to be like:

```
z=[a,b,x,y,z]
```

Answer (score 0):

try below code:

```
abc=[['a','b'],['c'],['x','y','z']]
pqr = ['a','b','x','y','z']
z=[c for l in abc for c in l if c in pqr]
```

output:

```
['a', 'b', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try, this also

```
from itertools import chain

abc=[['a','b'],['c'],['x','y','z','k']]
pqr = ['a','b','x','y','z','k','l']
result=[x for x in pqr if x in list(chain.from_iterable(abc))]
print result
```

**Output**

```
['a', 'b', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'k']
```

Comment: through chain.from_iterable(abc) redundancy cannot be removed

Comment: you didn't mentioned anything about redundancy in you problem, anyway `set(result)` will give you a unique list elements.

Comment: @Pam if my ans and comments helped you, you can accept my ans.